# Why load is not loading my data.text file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am tring to load my data.txt file's data in the position of "This is the first content". but it is giving me error/warning and not working.

> Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Users/SA/Desktop/ajax/data.txt' from origin 'null' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported
>   for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 GET file:///C:/Users/SA/Desktop/ajax/data.txt
>   net::ERR_FAILED send @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 ajax @
>   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 k.fn.load @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 (anonymous) @
>   trynew.html:16 dispatch @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 v.handle @
>   jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: GET
>   "file:///C:/Users/SA/Desktop/ajax/data.txt".

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX</title>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script >
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $("#btn").click(function() 
            {
                $("#test").load("data.txt", function(){
                    alert("this is the message for a moron");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id="test"> This is the first content </p>
    </div>
<button id="btn">Click the button to change</button>    
</body>
</html>
```

data.txt

```
<p>Hello this is the new text punk!</p>
```

Comment: You cannot make AJAX requests to the local file system, for obvious security reasons. You need to install a webserver on your machine and run your code on that.

Comment: More info here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Thanks, since I am new to ajax/jquery/javascript didn't figure it out myself